# Do I need Applicative Pretext for using Traversal with Lens?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have a function that I believe is stricter than lens because of `Applicative f` context.

```
Prelude Text.XML.Lens Data.Maybe Data.String Text.XML> :t f
f :: Control.Applicative.Applicative f =>
     (Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document
```

This is because I obtained it from some `Traversal`.

```
Prelude Text.XML.Lens Data.Maybe Data.String Text.XML> let f = root ./ ell "parent"
```

I want to pass it to a function that expects a monomorphic `ALens`:

```
Prelude Text.XML.Lens Data.Maybe Data.String Text.XML> :t textFrom
textFrom
  :: Data.Text.Internal.Text
     -> s -> ALens s s Element Element -> Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
Prelude Text.XML.Lens Data.Maybe Data.String Text.XML> textFrom "groupId" pom f
```

But I don't really understand why this `Applicative` instance is needed. I must be using this API incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

```
    No instance for (Control.Applicative.Applicative
                       (Control.Lens.Internal.Context.Pretext (->) Element Element))
      arising from a use of ‘f’
    In the third argument of ‘textFrom’, namely ‘f’
    In the expression: textFrom "groupId" pom f
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = textFrom "groupId" pom f
Prelude Text.XML.Lens Data.Maybe Data.String Text.XML> :t f
f :: Control.Applicative.Applicative f =>
     (Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document
Prelude Text.XML.Lens Data.Maybe Data.String Text.XML> :t textFrom
textFrom
  :: Data.Text.Internal.Text
     -> s -> ALens s s Element Element -> Maybe Data.Text.Internal.Text
Prelude Text.XML.Lens Data.Maybe Data.String Text.XML> textFrom "groupId" pom f

<interactive>:68:24:
    No instance for (Control.Applicative.Applicative
                       (Control.Lens.Internal.Context.Pretext (->) Element Element))
      arising from a use of ‘f’
    In the third argument of ‘textFrom’, namely ‘f’
    In the expression: textFrom "groupId" pom f
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = textFrom "groupId" pom f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Answer

`f` isn't a `Lens`, so can't be used as `ALens`. [When you see `ALens` as an argument to a function, it expects a `Lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.4.0.2/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#t:ALens).

#### Long Answer

A polymorphic value that requires an `Applicative` instance can be used fewer places than a value that only requires a `Functor`.

```
Applicative f => (Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document -- :t f
Functor     f => (Element -> f Element) -> Document -> f Document -- :t Lens' Element Document
```

You'd like to pass `f` in place of an `ALens s s Element Element`. I'm going to work through what that type is. I'll use `E` in place of `Element` to keep this short

```
type ALens s t a b = LensLike (Pretext (->) a b) s t a b
     ALens s s E E = Lenslike (Pretext (->) E E) s s E E
```

The type gets really long when we substitute for `LensLike`. The only thing that's going on here is `Pretext (->) E E` is taking the place of `f` everywhere.

```
type LensLike f                  s t a b = (a -> f                  b) -> s -> f                  t
     LensLike (Pretext (->) E E) s s E E = (E -> (Pretext (->) E E) E) -> s -> (Pretext (->) E E) s
```

Comparing this to the type of `f` we have (I'm going to use `D` in place of `Document` to keep this short`.

```
Applicative f => (E -> f                  E) -> D -> f                  D  -- :t f
                 (E -> (Pretext (->) E E) E) -> s -> (Pretext (->) E E) s  -- ALens s s E E
```

In order to use a value of the first type where the second is needed there must be an `Applicative` instance for `Pretext (->) E E`, but a [`Pretext` only has a `Functor` instance](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.4.0.2/docs/Control-Lens-Internal-Context.html#t:Pretext). If `f` were actually a `Lens` and was defined for any `Functor` instead of any `Applicative` it would work here. That's the source of the error you are getting.